# Data Interoperability Conversion WFS Layer, Duplicate .XSI_NIL Field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, web-mapping, wfs, web-service, data-interoperability

When I use the data interoperability extension to retrieve a WFS dataset I have duplicate fields added with ".xsi_nil" added to the end of the field. However, if I use the WFS to Feature Class tool I do NOT get the ".xsi_nil" duplicate fields. I would like to be able to use the data interoperability extension to retrieve a WFS dataset WITH OUT the additional ".xsi_nil" field....any thoughts? (I am on 10.2, just FYI).

[image]

Comment: I have also seen that happening. ESRI support told that they do not investigate the case because the WFS server was not an ESRI server. To my understanding the WFS schema and GML data from the WFS server (TinyOWS, by the way) are totally valid and the issue is totally on the client side.

Comment: I double checked, the data was published via GeoServer. But, is there anything that I can doon my end, when I bring it into Arc, using the Data Interoperability extension to get rid of the duplicate ".xsi_nil" fields, or to populate them? Or is this something that has to be corrected on the GeoServer publishing side?

Comment: Also, does any one know what ".xsi_nil" means or is used for? THANKSSSSSSS!

Comment: AFAIK they are fake fields that the interoperability extension is creating when the GML from WFS server contains null values for some attributes. As a workaround you can try to update the source data to use some code like "N/A" instead of nulls.